# Powermock mockstatic Cannot subclass final class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, powermock

I am trying to mock a final class

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(TestFinalClass.class);
```

It is working from my eclipse when I run a single junit and add javaagent to my VM arguments

```
-javaagent:{path}/powermock-module-javaagent-1.6.4.jar
```

But when I try to run all test cases from command line using maven build command I am still getting "Cannot subclass final class"

Below is my snippet from pom.xml

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-javaagent:{path}/powermock-module-javaagent-1.6.4.jar</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 38):

```
package test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(FinalClass.class)
public class Tests {
    @Test
    public void test() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(FinalClass.class);
    }
}
```

This works for me. If you add 'PowerMockRunner' and 'PrepareForTest' annotations you don`t need to use extra vm arguments.

Answer (score 4):

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(FinalClass.class)
public class TestFinalClass{

    @Test
    public void whenMockFinalClassMockWorks() {

        FinalClass finalklass = PowerMockito.mock(FinalClass.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the code coverage using JaCoCo and need to make some changes related to it in the test class code. Those are as below:

1. I removed @RunWith annotation
2. Added @Rule and PowerMockRule class
3. Mentioned the Final and Static class in @PrepareForTest

   @PrepareForTest(FinalClass.class, StaticClass.class)

   public class Tests {

   ```
   @Rule
   public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

   @Test
   public void test() {
       PowerMockito.mockStatic(FinalClass.class);
       PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticClass.class);
   }
   ```

   }

Also added the argline in surefire to overcome the final class problem while mocking.

```
<configuration>
                <argLine>-javaagent:{path}/powermock-module-javaagent-1.6.4.jar</argLine>
            </configuration>
```